# How to change Nokia full touch lwuit form header color

Tags: java-me, lwuit, nokia, nokia-s40

I want to to change the header color of nokia lwuit based full touch form and i have tried setTitleComponent method but it is not working. Please also check the following link 
http://projects.developer.nokia.com/LWUIT_for_Series_40/wiki/UsingSeries40FullTouchFeatures
in which it is mentioned we cannot style the header but is it means we cannot change the bgcolor as well or put custom images in the header?

Comment: do you want to recreate the header part to be something like what I did in this question >> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13597932/lwuit-how-to-show-menu-commands-with-another-button

Answer (score 2):

Note that when using LWUIT for Series 40 port, the default way of running LWUIT apps is a normal-size canvas in Series 40 full touch devices. Thus the Series 40 chrome shows on top of canvas. And there is no way of customising it (other than the title text).

If you want to provide branding elements to the title, the options are:
1. create an additional lable below the Series 40 headerbar
2. run the application in full-screen. We are planning to create a high-level API for this but currently it is already possible using the following trick:
((GameCanvas) (javax.microedition.lcdui.Display.getDisplay(this)).getCurrent()).setFullScreenMode(true); 
In the latter option you will of course lose the Series 40 full touch layout.

Comment: does the "high-level API" is released to public?

Answer (score 0):

Use lwuit source, you can change method visibility if required, this is example what i used to use gradient color

```
        form.getTitleComponent().getStyle().setBackgroundType(Style.BACKGROUND_GRADIENT_LINEAR_VERTICAL);
        form.getTitleComponent().getStyle().setBackgroundGradientEndColor(Color.GRADIENT_END);
        form.getTitleComponent().getStyle().setBackgroundGradientStartColor(Color.GRADIENT_START);
        form.getTitleComponent().getStyle().setFgColor(Color.WHITE);
        form.getTitleComponent().getStyle().setPadding(10,10,0,0);
        form.getTitleComponent().getStyle().setFont(font);
```

Here `Color` is my custom class that is used for color code, you can use your one.

Comment: are u using it for nokia full touch devices? i need to change the header background...

Comment: I have used this line of code but unable to change the default background color of the header bar of full touch devices form.getTitleComponent().getStyle().setFgColor(0xffffff); Please suggest.

Comment: I've tried this code but unfortunately it doesn't work. I don't know why. Actually all of your code is make sense, it is the technical constraint from the device? I don't know

Comment: Ok, I finally get the source code of the Nokia SDK 2.0 but using this methods the header color still being in the same color! What can I do?