# LWUIT: How to show menu commands with another button

Tags: lwuit, nokia-s40

In LWUIT we could add the commands button right into the Form with `addCommand` function like in this link http://lwuit.java.net/tutorial/events.html . Because I am currently developing the Nokia Asha Full Touch Apps soto show those commands I could simply click it at the top left button.

However, I've created the custom title bar, so now I have the Button inside the container as the title bar I've made

[image: The custom bar I've made]

The 3 stripes above is the button with an image.

Do LWUIT have something like show menu like Android have `Activity.openOptionMenu` does?

Best Regards

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hi there!(my first post in stackoverflow)

You have to use PopupList component of com.nokia.mid.ui.
There is no problem to use this with LWUIT.

[PopupList javadoc](http://www.developer.nokia.com/Resources/Library/Java/_zip/GUID-237420DE-CCBE-4A74-A129-572E0708D428/com/nokia/mid/ui/PopupList.html)

As you can see in the javadoc. It is the example:

```
PopupList list1 = new PopupList();
PopupListItem item1 = new PopupListItem("Item1");
PopupListItem item2 = new PopupListItem("Item1", image1);
list1.appendItem(item1);
list1.appendItem(item2);
list1.setVisible(true);
```

The position of the menu will be good to your target.