# How to change color of title in header bar using lwuit?

Tags: lwuit, nokia-s40

I am using following code to set title :

super.setTitle("abc");

I just want to set color

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11960836/how-to-change-nokia-full-touch-lwuit-form-header-color

Comment: you may also find this helpful http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Discussion/showthread.php?237389-Customise-style-of-Title-action-button-1-and-action-button-2-on-Nokia-Asha-311

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The standard color in the title bar is defined by the color set in the settings options of the device. You can't change it from code. If you want, you can create another Label and hide the default title bar, but I don't recommended.

Comment: Thanks...You are right..We can not change the header bar colour from code.